# Feature engineering with MNAR data

Tags: missing-data, feature-engineering

I have logs from a user's keyboard, mouse, and a few other things. I am trying to use them in order to do some predictions. Exploring the data and trying some feature engineering, I have discovered that the *Hold Time* (duration between when a key is pressed and released in milliseconds) seems very promising.

In order to make predictions, the data is aggregated to be in the following form:

```
__________| keys pressed | mouse clicks | hold time mean |...| label
minute 1  |     X_11     |      X_12    |       X_13     |...| y_1
minute 2  |     X_21     |      X_22    |       X_23     |...| y_2
...              ...             ...             ...      ...  ...
minute N  |     X_N1     |      X_N2    |       X_N3     |...| y_N
```

The issue is that sometimes, a user would spend a minute without typing and thus computing a Hold Time mean makes no sense and creates a missing value. This obviously only happens when the value for `keys pressed` is zero.

I do not know how to handle these missing values. I do not want to drop all entries where the user was not typing, because I can rely on other features to do predictions in those cases. I thought that maybe putting the Hold Time mean to zero would make sense, since indeed the amount of time a key was held is zero, but this must bias my model?

Would anybody have any recommendation how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the 0 in `keys pressed` predicts missing data in `hold time mean`. Does any other field with data predict `hold time mean`? That in itself can be an interesting finding. You could also try to reformat your data where time is nested in observations (i.e., from a 'wide' format to a 'long' format), which would allow a longitudinal hierarchical linear model. In these kinds of models, listwise deletion is less deleterious.

Comment: 0 in ´keys pressed´ does indeed predict missing value in ´hold time mean´, but no other value or feature can predict ´hold time mean´. I am not sure how I could convert my data from 'wide' to 'long', or how it could help. Could you please explain?

Comment: It also looks like your data is already formatted for a longitudinal hierarchical model.

I like the Raudenbush & Bryk (2002) test for multi-level modelling.

Comment: Your model might look like this:


$Level 1:$

$hold.time.mean=\beta_0+\beta_1(minute_{ij})+e_{ij}$

$Level 2:$

$\beta_0=\gamma_00+\gamma_01(keys.pressed_j)+\gamma_02(mouse.clicks_j)+U_0$

$\beta_1=\gamma_00+\gamma_01(keys.pressed_j)+\gamma_02(mouse.clicks_j)+U_1$